# Pandas - Load dataframe and show all columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I'm using the NBA Draft dataframe, which can be obtained [here](https://eimtgit.uoc.edu/prog_datasci_cat/prog_datasci_4/raw/ba658d89bd4e0ae4452ca22b1a077b6a7a2f4bae/data/historical_projections.csv?inline=false) and reading it with pandas.

When I try to load the csv to DataFrame the columns get sliced? with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
r = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/historical_projections.csv')
print r
```

The result:

```
                        Position                       ID  Draft Year  \
Player                                                                  
Karl-Anthony Towns             C       karl-anthony-towns        2015   
Justise Winslow               SF          justise-winslow        2015   
Stanley Johnson               SF          stanley-johnson        2015   
Jahlil Okafor                  C            jahlil-okafor        2015   
D`Angelo Russell              PG         d-angelo-russell        2015   
Dakari Johnson                 C           dakari-johnson        2015   
Devin Booker                  SG           3-devin-booker        2015   
Willie Cauley-Stein            C      willie-cauley-stein        2015   
Rondae Hollis-Jefferson       SF  rondae-hollis-jefferson        2015   
Trey Lyles                    PF               trey-lyles        2015   
Sam Dekker                    SF               sam-dekker        2015   
Kelly Oubre Jr.               SF           kelly-oubre-jr        2015   
Tyus Jones                    PG               tyus-jones        2015   
Kevon Looney                  PF             kevon-looney        2015   
Myles Turner                  PF           2-myles-turner        2015   
Cliff Alexander               PF          cliff-alexander        2015   
Christian Wood                PF           christian-wood        2015   
Frank Kaminsky                 C           frank-kaminsky        2015   
Michael Frazier II            SG       michael-frazier-ii        2015   
Brandon Ashley                PF           brandon-ashley        2015   
Bobby Portis                  PF             bobby-portis        2015   
Andrew Harrison               PG          andrew-harrison        2015   
Rashad Vaughn                 SG            rashad-vaughn        2015   
Aaron Harrison                SG         3-aaron-harrison        2015   
Montrezl Harrell              PF         montrezl-harrell        2015   
Quinn Cook                    PG               quinn-cook        2015   
Cameron Payne                 PG          2-cameron-payne        2015   
Chris McCullough              PF         chris-mccullough        2015   
Justin Anderson               SF          justin-anderson        2015   
Terry Rozier                  PG             terry-rozier        2015   
...                          ...                      ...         ...   
Jeff Trepagnier               SG          jeff-trepagnier        2001   
Jeryl Sasser                  PG             jeryl-sasser        2001   
Terence Morris                SF           terence-morris        2001   
SirValiant Brown              PG         sirvaliant-brown        2001   
Michael Wright                PF           michael-wright        2001   
Maurice Evans                 SG            maurice-evans        2001   
Alvin Jones                    C              alvin-jones        2001   
Jerry Green                   SG              jerry-green        2001   
Kenny Gregory                 SF            kenny-gregory        2001   
Casey Calvary                 PF            casey-calvary        2001   
Lee Scruggs                   SF              lee-scruggs        2001   
Rashad Phillips               PG          rashad-phillips        2001   
Brian Scalabrine              PF         brian-scalabrine        2001   
Kirk Haston                   PF              kirk-haston        2001   
Kimani Ffriend                 C           kimani-ffriend        2001   
Damone Brown                  SF             damone-brown        2001   
Darren Kelly                  SG             darren-kelly        2001   
Michael Hicks                 SG         11-michael-hicks        2001   
Will Solomon                  PG             will-solomon        2001   
Monty Mack                    SG               monty-mack        2001   
Dean Oliver                   PG              dean-oliver        2001   
Sean Lampley                  SF             sean-lampley        2001   
Terry Black                   SF              terry-black        2001   
Cookie Belcher                PG           cookie-belcher        2001   
Eric Chenowith                 C           eric-chenowith        2001   
Terrell Lyday                 SG            terrell-lyday        2001   
Brandon Wolfram               SF          brandon-wolfram        2001   
Ruben Boumtje Boumtje          C    ruben-boumtje-boumtje        2001   
Greg Stevenson                SG           greg-stevenson        2001   
Calvin Bowman                  C            calvin-bowman        2001   

                         Projected SPM  Superstar   Starter  Role Player  \
Player                                                                     
Karl-Anthony Towns            1.030606   0.134767  0.427183     0.163083   
Justise Winslow               0.875329   0.083529  0.510905     0.176767   
Stanley Johnson               0.679493   0.067800  0.423733     0.278500   
Jahlil Okafor                 0.521661   0.058717  0.409900     0.235533   
D`Angelo Russell              0.511967   0.152033  0.342283     0.096583   
Dakari Johnson                0.491787   0.021341  0.367544     0.417572   
Devin Booker                  0.472577   0.073367  0.324467     0.390167   
Willie Cauley-Stein           0.351171   0.047114  0.405990     0.243186   
Rondae Hollis-Jefferson       0.311909   0.014590  0.368533     0.392481   
Trey Lyles                    0.267509   0.022386  0.351329     0.403052   
Sam Dekker                    0.254165   0.008692  0.385004     0.329054   
Kelly Oubre Jr.               0.247310   0.019833  0.378983     0.337967   
Tyus Jones                    0.243549   0.027200  0.414562     0.284405   
Kevon Looney                  0.204173   0.008300  0.355567     0.374917   
Myles Turner                  0.076381   0.029417  0.335798     0.318517   
Cliff Alexander               0.026134   0.007633  0.294783     0.406617   
Christian Wood               -0.019561   0.008397  0.311111     0.393688   
Frank Kaminsky               -0.072352   0.006718  0.352835     0.327164   
Michael Frazier II           -0.167051   0.010084  0.254307     0.381989   
Brandon Ashley               -0.170210   0.011187  0.253265     0.356139   
Bobby Portis                 -0.314574   0.003141  0.253027     0.386533   
Andrew Harrison              -0.337041   0.011228  0.209973     0.393991   
Rashad Vaughn                -0.342326   0.020667  0.242333     0.367800   
Aaron Harrison               -0.420844   0.009669  0.191223     0.391380   
Montrezl Harrell             -0.436183   0.003904  0.200321     0.411584   
Quinn Cook                   -0.453518   0.000128  0.221395     0.365234   
Cameron Payne                -0.604345   0.009530  0.190084     0.316888   
Chris McCullough             -0.630996   0.006567  0.192133     0.293200   
Justin Anderson              -0.635745   0.000926  0.157187     0.412167   
Terry Rozier                 -0.637634   0.007467  0.188248     0.299670   
...                                ...        ...       ...          ...   
Jeff Trepagnier              -0.911776   0.003727  0.097090     0.380866   
Jeryl Sasser                 -0.915548   0.001558  0.056811     0.528500   
Terence Morris               -0.936639   0.001284  0.106538     0.380679   
SirValiant Brown             -0.951670   0.004985  0.102306     0.349285   
Michael Wright               -1.051887   0.004342  0.074562     0.367175   
Maurice Evans                -1.065428   0.001411  0.060288     0.409847   
Alvin Jones                  -1.088554   0.000694  0.062898     0.382907   
Jerry Green                  -1.103679   0.004745  0.045049     0.393803   
Kenny Gregory                -1.105271   0.000606  0.061600     0.389261   
Casey Calvary                -1.108822   0.001052  0.058460     0.391861   
Lee Scruggs                  -1.163638   0.000261  0.042095     0.358225   
Rashad Phillips              -1.230746   0.001420  0.031098     0.354066   
Brian Scalabrine             -1.245361   0.000000  0.017496     0.402688   
Kirk Haston                  -1.251493   0.002086  0.039629     0.327627   
Kimani Ffriend               -1.257651   0.000810  0.060046     0.304163   
Damone Brown                 -1.259393   0.000000  0.043803     0.335953   
Darren Kelly                 -1.273854   0.000000  0.040028     0.339174   
Michael Hicks                -1.301079   0.000338  0.018563     0.356263   
Will Solomon                 -1.301901   0.000000  0.025063     0.342152   
Monty Mack                   -1.348996   0.000140  0.016068     0.352727   
Dean Oliver                  -1.359015   0.000145  0.028928     0.309891   
Sean Lampley                 -1.379912   0.000797  0.018403     0.308882   
Terry Black                  -1.398119   0.000680  0.022434     0.291499   
Cookie Belcher               -1.453962   0.003407  0.038351     0.227702   
Eric Chenowith               -1.462131   0.000548  0.030222     0.236204   
Terrell Lyday                -1.486319   0.001152  0.018303     0.261035   
Brandon Wolfram              -1.493460   0.000271  0.011532     0.271560   
Ruben Boumtje Boumtje        -1.494069   0.000000  0.020653     0.236919   
Greg Stevenson               -1.529188   0.000000  0.019693     0.238861   
Calvin Bowman                -1.684669   0.000000  0.005068     0.168629   

                             Bust  
Player                             
Karl-Anthony Towns       0.274967  
Justise Winslow          0.228800  
Stanley Johnson          0.229967  
Jahlil Okafor            0.295850  
D`Angelo Russell         0.409100  
Dakari Johnson           0.193544  
Devin Booker             0.212000  
Willie Cauley-Stein      0.303710  
Rondae Hollis-Jefferson  0.224396  
Trey Lyles               0.223233  
Sam Dekker               0.277250  
Kelly Oubre Jr.          0.263217  
Tyus Jones               0.273833  
Kevon Looney             0.261217  
Myles Turner             0.316269  
Cliff Alexander          0.290967  
Christian Wood           0.286804  
Frank Kaminsky           0.313283  
Michael Frazier II       0.353620  
Brandon Ashley           0.379410  
Bobby Portis             0.357298  
Andrew Harrison          0.384809  
Rashad Vaughn            0.369200  
Aaron Harrison           0.407728  
Montrezl Harrell         0.384191  
Quinn Cook               0.413243  
Cameron Payne            0.483498  
Chris McCullough         0.508100  
Justin Anderson          0.429720  
Terry Rozier             0.504615  
...                           ...  
Jeff Trepagnier          0.518318  
Jeryl Sasser             0.413132  
Terence Morris           0.511499  
SirValiant Brown         0.543423  
Michael Wright           0.553921  
Maurice Evans            0.528454  
Alvin Jones              0.553500  
Jerry Green              0.556404  
Kenny Gregory            0.548532  
Casey Calvary            0.548627  
Lee Scruggs              0.599418  
Rashad Phillips          0.613415  
Brian Scalabrine         0.579816  
Kirk Haston              0.630658  
Kimani Ffriend           0.634980  
Damone Brown             0.620244  
Darren Kelly             0.620798  
Michael Hicks            0.624837  
Will Solomon             0.632785  
Monty Mack               0.631065  
Dean Oliver              0.661035  
Sean Lampley             0.671918  
Terry Black              0.685388  
Cookie Belcher           0.730541  
Eric Chenowith           0.733027  
Terrell Lyday            0.719510  
Brandon Wolfram          0.716636  
Ruben Boumtje Boumtje    0.742427  
Greg Stevenson           0.741446  
Calvin Bowman            0.826303
```

So I tried adding `index_col=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` but I still dont get what I want (you can see Bust on the right has a space):

```
                                                                                                                      Bust
Player                  Position ID                      Draft Year Projected SPM Superstar Starter  Role Player          
Karl-Anthony Towns      C        karl-anthony-towns      2015-01-01  1.030606     0.134767  0.427183 0.163083     0.274967
Justise Winslow         SF       justise-winslow         2015-01-01  0.875329     0.083529  0.510905 0.176767     0.228800
Stanley Johnson         SF       stanley-johnson         2015-01-01  0.679493     0.067800  0.423733 0.278500     0.229967
Jahlil Okafor           C        jahlil-okafor           2015-01-01  0.521661     0.058717  0.409900 0.235533     0.295850
D`Angelo Russell        PG       d-angelo-russell        2015-01-01  0.511967     0.152033  0.342283 0.096583     0.409100
```

So.. is there a way (I cant get skiprows to work) to present the DataFrame as clean as possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce the width of the dataframe output you can try the following things:

First, **round the float numbers as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383051/3254400) answer suggest**. To do so, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
r = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/historical_projections.csv')
r = r.round(2)
print r
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd
r = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/historical_projections.csv')
print r.round(2)
```

But be aware that this second option will not persist your changes in `r`, but only your *print* the rounded nunbers

If this is not enough, you can **reduce the column names lengths** using `.columns`:

```
r.columns = ['Pos', 'ID', 'Draft Year', 'Proj SPM', 'Star', 'Starter', 'Role', 'Bust']
```

The final code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
r = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/historical_projections.csv')
r = r.round(2)
r.columns = ['Pos', 'ID', 'Draft Year', 'Proj SPM', 'Star', 'Starter', 'Role', 'Bust']
print r
```

Comment: Hi Julian, tried your last "code" and this error pops up:

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 9 elements

Comment: When using round I can get an extra column of the first "batch" but it still doesnt show as a one block so to speak
I just wanted all columns to fit

Comment: I did a fix to my answer (I was using `Player` as a column and it's and index in your data). Check if the code now addresses the width problem.

Comment: I'm using IP[y] Notebook, so maybe the problem is on my side...
right now the split is 5 top 4 bottom haha

Comment: If you are using a notebook, you can use `display` instead of `print` (replace `print r` with `display(r)` in the last line). That should be a much more friendly representation!

Comment: It's a Python 2.7 notebook...
I tried display and it says NameError: name 'display' is not defined

Comment: You should be using an old version of the notebooks... try executing `from IPython.display import display` before running the `display`. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Julian the code you gave me helped a lot, but there is still one thing.

https://i.gyazo.com/01e9e583211671d34344437141cf504b.png

You can see that Player is down one row (as if it wasnt a title?) and the rest are okay?

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Great! This is because it's the index of the dataframe. You can move it to the level of the rest of the data running ` r = r.reset_index()` right after the statement where you set `r.columns=...`. This way a new index starting from `0...` will appear and the `Player` data will be a column as the rest. Please, accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see the whole dataframe in your screen? See if rounding suits your need

```
r.round(2)
```

Comment: Hi Ken, this actually doesnt change anything for me.. hmm :(

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you well. What is your objective? Is it to fit the dataframe width to the display?

Comment: Yes, I want all column to fit the width thats why I tried using index_col but I dont think its the right way